# Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption

Hi all i am usig AES for encryption, what i have done is i encrypted a data in a text file and and stored the a given location, decryption works fine if given in the same class file, i have created a different java class to decrypt the file, I am using the Javakeystore with username and password to store the keys and retrieve it and use the stored key to decrypt but i am getting the above error. Help me out guys. Here is the code for decryption.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;

public class Decrypto {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());

        /*
         * Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES128_CBC", "FlexiCore");
         * KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "FlexiCore");
         * SecretKey secKey = keyGen.generateKey();
         * System.out.println(secKey);
         */
        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES128_CBC", "FlexiCore");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\mykey.keystore"); // here
                                                                         // i am
                                                                         // uploading
        keyStore.load(fis, "javaci123".toCharArray());
        fis.close();
        Key secKey = (Key) keyStore.getKey("mySecretKey",
                "javaci123".toCharArray()); // line 35

        System.out.println("Found Key: " + (secKey));

        String cleartextFile = "C:\\cleartext.txt";
        String ciphertextFile = "C:\\ciphertextSymm.txt";

        // FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);

        String cleartextAgainFile = "C:\\cleartextAgainSymm.txt";

        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);

        // fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher1);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextAgainFile);
        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            cis.read(block, 0, i);
        }
        cis.close();
    }

}
```

error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not     properly padded
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.KeyProtector.unseal(KeyProtector.java:360)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineGetKey(JceKeyStore.java:133)
  at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source)
  at darm.code.com.Decrypto.main(Decrypto.java:35)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UnrecoverableKeyException` kind of identifies the problem, especially if the root cause is `"Given final block not properly padded"`. This basically means that your password is incorrect. The `KeyStore` will first generate a key from the given password and they uses that key to decrypt the stored key. If the decryption fails you hope for a MAC authentication error, but in this instance you get a padding error (which basically means that *somebody* forgot to add integrity protection to the container that contains the wrapped private key).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the issue in line 35

```
Key secKey = (Key) keyStore.getKey("mySecretKey",
        "javaci123".toCharArray()); // line 35
```

For encryption I had also set a password for the password i.e padding for the password is pw-password

```
Key secKey = (Key) keyStore.getKey("mySecretKey",
        "pw-password".toCharArray()); // line 35
```

after running I get the saved key to decrypt a simple logic I missed.

Found Key: ***********6fd******5**********